# Query to Return Missing Data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I have two tables with almost exact structure, but one table always seems to not be updated appropriately.  To show the issue, I have created two test tables that illustrate.

```
Declare @Test1 Table (card4 int, d1 date, amt float)
Declare @Test2 Table (card4 int, d1 date, amt float)

Insert Into @Test1 VALUES 
('4356', '01/01/2015', '12.24'), 
('4356', '01/01/2015', '44.12'), 
('1111', '01/01/2015', '55.10'), 
('2222', '01/01/2015', '23.12')
Insert Into @Test2 VALUES 
('4356', '01/01/2015', '12.24'), 
('4356', '01/02/2015', '11.11'),
 ('4356', '01/01/2015', '44.12')

Select * from @Test1
Select * from @Test2
```

From the sample data @Test1 is missing the `amt` 11.11 and I am not sure how to write a query that will pull all values from `@Test1` and any values that are missing from `@Test2`

This is the data set that I want returned

> `card4    d1          amt
>       1111    1/1/2015    55.1
>       2222    1/1/2015    23.12
>       4356    1/1/2015    12.24
>       4356    1/1/2015    44.12
>       4356    1/2/2015    11.11`

What would syntax be to achieve this?

Comment: You can use UNION between your two select statements to answer the question you asked. However, certain issues you mention (near identical tables, missing entries) point to other underlying problems.

Comment: @Forrest - Yes there are underlying problems.  These were 2 Spreadsheets that were received and imported into SQL that should have been identical...but were not.

Comment: Excel problems are myriad. This could be a simple problem with the cell formatting in a certain row. Good luck! The UNION will solve this question's problem, as @Forrest suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL's EXCEPT clause.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx

Values in the first table (the left query) that are not in the second (the right query) will be shown.  You can change the table order to achieve the opposite.

```
select * from @Test1
except
select * from @Test2


card4       d1         amt
----------- ---------- ----------------------
1111        2015-01-01 55.1
2222        2015-01-01 23.12
```

Comment: Maybe, I worded my ? incorrectly, I want all non duplicate results to be returned.  This seems to return data that is in one table and not the other.

Comment: I mis-understood the question.  I'll leave this here for a bit then vote to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear on your question however if I go by below comment

> I want all non duplicate results to be returned

I would like to write code as below:

```
(Select * from @Test1
except
Select * from @Test2)
union
(Select * from @Test2
except 
Select * from @Test1
)
```

This would give you all non-duplicate value among these two tables:

[image: Result]

This can be achieved using CTE also however I feel except is good candidate here.

Kindly let us know if this is what you were looking for.